# Use last container name as default in docker client

Tags: docker, boot2docker

docker client for `docker ps` has very useful flag `-l` which shows container information which was run recently. However all other docker commands requires providing either `CONTAINER ID` or `NAME`.

Is there any nice trick which would allow to call:

```
docker logs -f -l
```

instead of:

```
docker logs -f random_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while playing with docker tutorial, I created small set of aliases:

```
alias docker_last="docker ps -l | tail -n +2 | awk '{ print \$(NF) }' | xargs docker $1"
alias docker_all="docker ps -a | tail -n +2 | awk '{ print \$(NF) }' | xargs docker $1"
alias docker_up="docker ps | tail -n +2 | awk '{ print \$(NF) }' | xargs docker $1"
alias docker_down="docker ps -a | tail -n +2 | grep -v Up | awk '{ print \$(NF) }' | xargs docker $1"
```

Which allow to call command on last, all, up and down containers:

```
docker_last logs # Display logs from last created container
docker_down rm   # Remove all stopped containers
docker_up stop   # Stop all running containers
```

Answer (score 3):

You can you `` docker logs -f `docker ps -ql` ``

Answer (score 1):

For the last container
`docker ps -n 1`
or variants such as 
`docker ps -qan 1`
can be handy